# Instagram liker python script doesn't click the like button

Tags: python

My script was running as intended for quite awhile and one day it stopped liking the photos. I can't seem to figure out what is going wrong or what I changed.

```
import selenium
import selenium.webdriver.common.keys
import time
import random
import sys

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import random
import sys


def print_same_line(text):
    sys.stdout.write('\r')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stdout.write(text)
    sys.stdout.flush()

  
class InstagramBot:

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def closeBrowser(self):
        self.driver.close()

    def login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
        time.sleep(4)
        user_name_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
        user_name_elem.clear()
        user_name_elem.send_keys(self.username)
        passworword_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
        passworword_elem.clear()
        passworword_elem.send_keys(self.password)
        passworword_elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(4)


    def like_photo(self, hashtag):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/" + hashtag + "/")
        time.sleep(4)

        # gathering photos
        pic_hrefs = []
        for i in range(1, 7):
            try:
                driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
                time.sleep(4)
                # get tags
                hrefs_in_view = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
                # finding relevant hrefs
                hrefs_in_view = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in hrefs_in_view
                                 if '.com/p/' in elem.get_attribute('href')]
                # building list of unique photos
                [pic_hrefs.append(href) for href in hrefs_in_view if href not in pic_hrefs]
                # print("Check: pic href length " + str(len(pic_hrefs)))
            except Exception:
                continue

        # Liking photos
        unique_photos = len(pic_hrefs)
        for pic_href in pic_hrefs:
            driver.get(pic_href)
            time.sleep(3)
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(top);")
            try:
                time.sleep(3)
                like_button = lambda: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//svg[@aria-label="Like"]').click()
                like_button().click()
                for second in reversed(range(0, random.randint(100, 200))):
                    print_same_line("#" + hashtag + ': unique photos left: ' + str(unique_photos)
                                    + " | Sleeping " + str(second))
                    time.sleep(3)
            except Exception as e:
                time.sleep(3)
            unique_photos -= 1

if __name__ == "__main__":

    username = "xxxxxxxxxxxx`enter code here`"
    password = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"

    ig = InstagramBot(username, password)
    ig.login()

    hashtags = ['run', 'runner', 'running', 'seenonmyrun', 'fit',
                'runtoinspire', 'furtherfasterstronger', 'trailrunning', 'trailrunner', 'runchat', 'runhappy',
                'time2run', 'happyrunner', 'marathon', 'runners', 'trailrun',
                'fitness', 'workout', 'cardio', 'training', 'instarunner', 'instarun', 'austinrunning', 'austin']

    while True:
        try:
            # Choose a random tag from the list of tags
            tag = random.choice(hashtags)
            ig.like_photo(tag)
        except Exception:
            ig.closeBrowser()
            time.sleep(60)
            ig = InstagramBot(username, password)
            ig.login()
```

I believe it's these couple of lines that are the problem but I could be wrong

```
like_button = lambda: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//svg[@aria-label="Like"]').click()
                like_button().click()
```

I'm running this in pycharm if that's helpful as well. Any advice would be really appreciated.

This is the HTML of the like button that I can't get clicked

```
<svg aria-label="Like" class="_8-yf5 " color="#8e8e8e" fill="#8e8e8e" height="24" role="img" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24"><path d="M34.6 6.1c5.7 0 10.4 5.2 10.4 11.5 0 6.8-5.9 11-11.5 16S25 41.3 24 41.9c-1.1-.7-4.7-4-9.5-8.3-5.7-5-11.5-9.2-11.5-16C3 11.3 7.7 6.1 13.4 6.1c4.2 0 6.5 2 8.1 4.3 1.9 2.6 2.2 3.9 2.5 3.9.3 0 .6-1.3 2.5-3.9 1.6-2.3 3.9-4.3 8.1-4.3m0-3c-4.5 0-7.9 1.8-10.6 5.6-2.7-3.7-6.1-5.5-10.6-5.5C6 3.1 0 9.6 0 17.6c0 7.3 5.4 12 10.6 16.5.6.5 1.3 1.1 1.9 1.7l2.3 2c4.4 3.9 6.6 5.9 7.6 6.5.5.3 1.1.5 1.6.5.6 0 1.1-.2 1.6-.5 1-.6 2.8-2.2 7.8-6.8l2-1.8c.7-.6 1.3-1.2 2-1.7C42.7 29.6 48 25 48 17.6c0-8-6-14.5-13.4-14.5z"></path></svg>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to put the html of the element you are trying to find.

Comment: @NathanRoberts Gotcha. I'm aiming for the like button which if I copy the html in the inspect section is the following:

Comment: @NathanRoberts <svg aria-label="Like" class="_8-yf5 " color="#8e8e8e" fill="#8e8e8e" height="24" role="img" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24">

Comment: @NathanRoberts <path d="M34.6 6.1c5.7 0 10.4 5.2 10.4 11.5 0 6.8-5.9 11-11.5 16S25 41.3 24 41.9c-1.1-.7-4.7-4-9.5-8.3-5.7-5-11.5-9.2-11.5-16C3 11.3 7.7 6.1 13.4 6.1c4.2 0 6.5 2 8.1 4.3 1.9 2.6 2.2 3.9 2.5 3.9.3 0 .6-1.3 2.5-3.9 1.6-2.3 3.9-4.3 8.1-4.3m0-3c-4.5 0-7.9 1.8-10.6 5.6-2.7-3.7-6.1-5.5-10.6-5.5C6 3.1 0 9.6 0 17.6c0 7.3 5.4 12 10.6 16.5.6.5 1.3 1.1 1.9 1.7l2.3 2c4.4 3.9 6.6 5.9 7.6 6.5.5.3 1.1.5 1.6.5.6 0 1.1-.2 1.6-.5 1-.6 2.8-2.2 7.8-6.8l2-1.8c.7-.6 1.3-1.2 2-1.7C42.7 29.6 48 25 48 17.6c0-8-6-14.5-13.4-14.5z"></path></svg>

Comment: You should edit it into your post in a code block so it is easier to read.

Comment: @NathanRoberts good call. Sorry, this is my first time posting here.

Comment: @JasonCasady did u find a solution?